# What is the difference between "oins, zwoi, drei" vs. "eins zwei, drei"?

Tags: german-to-english, numbers

What is the difference between *oins, zwoi, drei* vs. *eins zwei, drei*?

An example of this is when counting down for a race or in the song *Ein Prosit*.

Comment: *Oins* is just an onomatopoeia of the southern pronounciation of "eins", same with *zwoi*. In northern Germany, people say *eens*, *zwe*, *dre* instead.

Comment: Those are Swabian dialect. However, the 'n' is often not pronounced, so it rather sounds like "ois". Also note the difference from "oans" and "zwoa", which are Bavarian and are pronounced more gutturally.

Answer (score 2):

This is standard German:

> eins, zwei, drei

But this is a dialect:

> oins, zwoi, drei

German has lots of dialects. I live in Austria, and there every valley in the Alps has its own distinct dialect.

I have no idea from which region this dialect is, because I never have heard »zwoi« as a version of »zwei«.

There is an article about German dialects in [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_dialects). But in [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Dialekte) you find much more detailed information about German dialects.

Comment: Appears to be Swabian (~Stuttgart) (Edit: user DeeDuu mentioned this as comment to the Q before I did here, sorry.)